# Bash - lost new line characters after zip

Tags: bash, shell, unix, zip

I write `BASH` script to dump logs from remote server. Dump process is ok, because after that I have big `DUMPLOG.log` file with necessary information:

```
ACTION A
ACTION B
ACTION C
ACTION A
```

but after I call: `zip "DUMPLOG" "DUMPLOG.log"` my file after unzip looks like this:

```
ACTION A ACTION B ACTION C ACTION A
```

Is it possible not to lose newline characters in a file `DUMPLOG.log` after `zip` action, but have still good compression?

Thanks for any advice

**EDIT**

> After I zip my `DUMLOG.log` file (remote linux machine), I send it on email, and unizp on windows machine, and then I have log file without new line character.

Comment: Are you zipping a file used on a Windows machine?

Comment: No is remote linux machine. After I zip my `DUMPLOG.log` file, I send it on e-mail. Next, I unzip it on windows machine, and then I have log file without new line character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mentioned the problem yourself,

> unizp on windows machine, and then I have log file without new line character

Since your remote server is Linux based, the selected line ending for text files will be the Linux native one (i.e. `LF`) which you need to convert to have both  a `Carriage Return (CR)` followed by a `Line Feed (LF)`, `CRLF` in short when need to use on a Windows machine. Use a tool [`unix2dos`](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/unix2dos1.html), which is meant for that.

Use `unix2dos` on all your `.log` files before zipping it, which should solve your problem.